# get value of variable from procedure pyodbc

Tags: python, oracle, odbc, pyodbc

I have a problem with procedure and pyodbc, I need to replicate the following:

```
var OUT_ID_PRODUCTO NUMBER;

EXECUTE SP_AGREGA_PRODUCTO (5000,:OUT_ID_PRODUCTO);

PRINT :OUT_ID_PRODUCTO;
```

In python I have this to execute the procedure:

```
cursor.execute("{call SP_AGREGA_PRODUCTO(?,?)}", "899",":OUT_ID_PRODUCTO")
conn.commit()
cursor.execute("PRINT :OUT_ID_PRODUCTO")
conn.commit()
```

The procedure works, but to get the variable it gives me this error: /

```
('42000', '[42000] [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement\n\x00吆\x01\x00鉰❲\x01\x00\u0e00뾜翮\x00鳠\ue4bb翾\x00杕⛫\x01\x00ո셈翮\x00ꗰ쓔翮\x00\x90슐翮\x00\u0e00뾜翮\x00\x00슐翮\x00ꗰ쓔翮\x00鵀\ue4bb翾\x00摡⛫\x01\x00 (900) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

Is there a way to replicate the print?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunatly stored functions nor out variables of stored procedures or functions can be accessed directly - you need a trick by using

```
SELECT ... FROM DUAL
```

Please see below example

```
#
# create or replace procedure SP_AGREGA_PRODUCTO(n1 in number, n2 out NOCOPY number) is
# begin
#   n2 := n1 * 5;
# end;
# 
x = "BEGIN SP_AGREGA_PRODUCTO(:A,:B); END;"
A = 1
B = 2
cur = cn.cursor()
c = cur.execute(x,A,B)
# Wont work 
print (B)

#create or replace function SF_AGREGA_PRODUCTO(n1 in number) return number is
#begin
#  return n1 * 5;
#end;
#/ 
# So we have to use a SELECT to query a 
x = "SELECT SF_AGREGA_PRODUCTO(:A) FROM DUAL;"
A = 1
cur = cn.cursor()
cur.execute(x,A)
row = cur.fetchone() 
if row: 
    print(row[0])
```

OUTPUT

```
2
5.0
```

Comment: I can't change the procedure so that it has the return 
using "{call...", it works fine, the problem is the variable that does not return anything 
I'll look for other options then, thank you very much 

Comment: If odbc is not mandatory you may try cx_oracle - the open Source Python library accessing Oracle DB - can be downloaded from Oracle page - uses the ODPI interface which sits ontop of OCI - ODBC used OCI, to. Anyway - looks to be a limitation to pyodbc since SQL Server faces the same  problem